# "On" or "at" a tangent?

Tags: word-choice

An idle train of thought earlier today led me to thinking about the use of the word "tangent" when applied to unrelated trains of thought or conversation.
It struck me that I have heard people use *"... went off on a tangent."* and *"...went off at a tangent."*, or equivalent phrasing, completely interchangeably.

So my question is whether either of these is preferred under specific circumstances or if they're both applicable in all circumstances.

Comment: **At** would seem to imply that you're going in the direction of the tangent, while **on** would connote that your are actually following through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** Take your pick.

In geometry, a tangent (from the Latin *tangere*, to touch) to a curve is a straight line that shares a common point with the curve but otherwise does not intersect it:
[image]

Figuratively, a tangent in a conversation is the discussion of a topic that touches the original discussion at one point but veers off into other, unrelated areas never to return. The word *off* used with *tangent* licenses a number of complementary prepositional phrases. The google shows a 2:1 preference for *on a tangent* over *at a tangent*, and the Ngram viewer [shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off%20*%20a%20tangent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Coff%20%2A%20a%20tangent%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boff%20at%20a%20tangent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boff%20on%20a%20tangent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boff%20in%20a%20tangent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boff%20along%20a%20tangent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boff%20into%20a%20tangent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boff%20onto%20a%20tangent%3B%2Cc0) preference for the former, but only in the last couple of decades.

[*You Need This Book to get what you want*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5W0mAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT15&dq=%22off%20on%20a%20tangent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCrdy7qNTOAhVBKCYKHV-NBcQQ6AEIUjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22off%20on%20a%20tangent%22&f=false) by M Palmer and 
S Solder illustrates the usage with *on*:

> You rarely drift off when someone goes **off on a tangent**, do you?
>   You actually hang on to every word, wondering when the speaker will
>   get back to the point.

As you can tell by examining the figure above, the tangent forms different angles with the coordinate axes depending on the point of tangency. The attraction of the phrase "at an angle" may be the reason that people prefer *at* with tangents, or it may be the influence of the place to which the tangent leads.  For instance, consider [*The Concept of A University*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4Gcp-hZpVPMC&pg=PA221&dq=%22off%20at%20a%20tangent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL19qWotTOAhXJYyYKHXf0DV4Q6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=%22off%20at%20a%20tangent%22&f=false) by K R Minogue

> If the lives of most people take place within the warm circles of
>   practice, the academic world is to be found flying **off at a
>   tangent** - a situation it shares with art and lunacy. But a tangent
>   is a lonely place,....

The idea of destination yields two other less-favored variations *off into a tangent* and *off onto a tangent*. From [*From the Outer World*](https://books.google.com/books?id=MEgWaMYswb0C&q=%22off%20into%20a%20tangent%22&dq=%22off%20into%20a%20tangent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia-8GZrdTOAhWI7yYKHYJxAEQQ6AEIHjAA) by O and L Handlin:

> the Japanese, for they do not fly **off into a tangent**, nor do they take up dangerous weapons, nor do they hurt other people.

and from [*Making Friends, Keeping Friends*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yq3-pCVeUkwC&q=%22off%20onto%20a%20tangent%22&dq=%22off%20onto%20a%20tangent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1v8HDrtTOAhUC5iYKHUnUC34Q6AEINTAF) by J Hearn:

> We are most likely to fly **off onto a tangent** of accusation and probing at weak points in the other person's defenses where they can be hurt the most

Other choices include *in*, which if the Ngram viewer is to be trusted, is used mainly older sources mainly related to mathematics and physics. Thus from [*Hawkins' mechanical dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=HLlXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA572&dq=%22off%20in%20a%20tangent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim9KDkqdTOAhVGPCYKHTlwDjsQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22off%20in%20a%20tangent%22&f=false) by N Hawkins (1909):

> In physics, a force which acts so as to give a tendency to a revolving
>   body to fly **off in a tangent** to its orbit.

*Along a tangent* is used in the same way in the same type of (though more modern) venues, but I recommend the contribution of Harlequin Romances' [*Claimed by the Desert Prince*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SLwjLM5b5TMC&pg=PA33&dq=%22off%20along%20a%20tangent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbzq64q9TOAhUG6yYKHTnhC-A4ChDoAQgsMAM#v=onepage&q=%22off%20along%20a%20tangent%22&f=false) by M Webber (if only for its cover photo and tagline *Dedicated, daring, and devastatingly handsome -- these doctors are guaranteed to raise your temperature*):

> But Kam's mind was already racing **off along a tangent**....

Comment: I think your diagram makes a stronger case for "on" than any other preposition and based upon personal recollection, I would suppose that is the default form unless context calls for otherwise. <del>Would you please include some Google Ngram or other corpora based data in your answer</del>, and maybe provide some explanation regarding why the prepositions are being chosen in each sentence? P.S. Ah, I see you included a link. I'm very used to seeing screenshots in the body of an answer from most users, which is done, perhaps, to provide some backup in-case google ever stops offering nGrams.

Comment: @Tonepoet Keep in mind that the diagram is a literal depiction of a tangent, so I'd be hesitant to conclude anything about the diagram's force for making a case for the figurative. I do give a link to Ngram results in the answer. I'd guess that "on a tangent" is related to being on a path, since both tangents and paths are represented by lines, but that's just a guess and doesn't explain why "at a tangent" used to be more popular according to the Ngram viewer. For *at*, *into*, and *onto*, the cites treat the tangent as a destination and not a journey [con't]->

Comment: @Tonepoet <-[con't] which may make those prepositions more apt for that sense, but I'm loath to draw a definite conclusion from singular instances. The why of idioms is a tricky business, and I'm not convinced it's amenable to definite conclusions.